# Attaching event listeners from external script file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I moved from classic HTML to React.

My classic HTML had external JavaScript, which attached even listeners upon `$(document).ready()`. This doesn't work anymore, as `$(document).ready()` is triggered before React renders the elements.

To attach the even listeners to the React page, I tried to use `componentDidMount()` as below, but the even listeners are not being attached.

reactJS.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


class Question extends React.Component {
    render() {
        ...
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: []};
    }

    loadQuestionsFromServer() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this)
        })
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.loadQuestionsFromServer();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        alert("component did mount");
        window.attach_listeners();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello React</h1>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.data.map(function(question, i) {
                        return <Question key={i} question={question} />
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App url='/questions/test.json'/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

There is a `console.log()` when `attach_listeners();` is run and I see that `componentDidMount()` does trigger it.

If I manually type `window.attach_listeners();` into the console it works.

Is `attach_listeners()` getting triggered too early maybe? When the `alert()` under `componentDidMount()` pops up, I still can't see the page. But `componentDidMount()` would be after `render()` I thought.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
See below for a basic idea of `attach_listeners();`. This is in an external JavaScript file, which loads correctly as far as I can tell.

```
function attach_listeners() {
    $('input.answer').keydown(function(event) {
        ...
    });

    $("a.answer").click(function() {
        ...
    });

    $("a.showanswer").click(function() {
        ...
    });

    $("input").focus(function(e) {
        ...
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you show your `attach_listeners()` method too?

Comment: Oh! Are the elements that you are attaching events to (`input.answer`,...) in the `Question` component?

Comment: Yes, they are. When I put `window.attach_listeners()` in the console it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register for the events, the data isn't yet loaded from the server, the `Question` component aren't yet mounted and thus the events is not attached to anything at all.

**Explanation:**

1. In `componentWillMount`, you request for the data from server, this is correct and recommended, but the request is asynchronous and the state is change only when the data is returned from the server..
2. When `componentDidMount`, the data is not available, so the only elements rendered in the DOM is the `h1` and `ul` (with no element inside).
3. You register for events inside the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, because there's no such elements in the DOM, the callbacks are not registered.
4. The data is returned, the `setState` method called and the state updated with the new data.
5. The `App` component rerender with the new state, the `Question` component (together with its DOM elements `input.answer`,...) get rendered. Because this happen after you registered the event, the callbacks is not attached to them.
6. Now, when all the elements are mounted. You call the `attach_listeners` method and it attach the event listener to the elements correctly.

**Solution:**

1. **The recommended React way:** you should put the callbacks as methods of your `App` component, and pass them into your `Question` components inside the `render` method, like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).
2. Put your `attach_listeners` method call into `componentDidUpdate`. This way, your callbacks is sure to be registered, but you must be aware that if your component get rerendered again, the callbacks will be registered **twice or more**, as the `componentDidUpdate` is called after each rerender except the first.
3. Give your `attach_listener` a `id` param to attach to only the elements with that `id`. Add an `id` to each of your `Question`, and put your `attach_listener` call to the `componentDidMount` of the `Question` component with its `id` as the argument.

Comment: OK, so best to do all the event handling in React and not an external JS file.

Comment: Yes, JS frameworks generally discourage user from using non framework way to manipulate DOM and adding event listeners, because it may leads to wierd, undesired and hard to debug behaviors. React, because it uses a virtual DOM beside the real DOM, is even more prone to this problem.

Comment: I will have to redo everything in React what already worked the "old" way, but I guess there isn't a way around this if I also want it to be robust.

Answer (score 0):

Your `attach_listeners()` is appointing to original elements, so only works when you manually type in browser console.
Event callback is bound to the react component and not the original element.
See here:

https://shripadk.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html